# Large dataset with pyspark - optimizing join, sort, compare between rows and group by with aggregation

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-mining, apache-spark

I have a csv file with more than 700,000,000 records in this structure:

```
product_id      start_date       end_date
1               19-Jan-2000      20-Mar-2000
1               20-Mar-2000      25-Apr-2000
1               20-May-2000      27-Jul-2000
1               27-Jul-2000      
2               20-Mar-2000      25-Apr-2000
3               12-Jan-2010      30-Mar-2010
3               30-Mar-2010
```

`End_date` is `null` means product currently is in used.

`End_date` can mean 2 things, 1 - disable product, 2 - battery replace

If `End_date` is the same as the next `start_date`, then it is battery replacement.

The expect result is, `product_id` along with the `start_date` of its current lifecycle (battery replace is counted in current lifecycle).

Which mean, the `start_date` should be the date after its last disability. For example above, output would be:

```
product_id      start_date       
1               20-May-2000
3               12-Jan-2010
```

My code is as below. It's kind of ugly, so if you could please review and advise if this code can run well with 700,000,000 records or there are better ways/methods to solve this challenge. I have run this code and seem a little bit slow for 100 records test file.Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
# csv input
df = spark.read.csv('productlist.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)

# filter out stopped product id 
df2 = df.select("product_id").filter("end_date is null")
df = df.join(df2, ["product_id"])

# sort dataframe by product id & start date desc
df = df.sort(['product_id', 'start_date'],ascending=False)

# create window to add next start date of the product
w = Window.partitionBy("product_id").orderBy(desc("product_id"))
df = df.withColumn("next_time", F.lag(df.start_date).over(w))

# add column to classify if the change of the current record is product disability or battery change.
df = df.withColumn('diff', F.when(F.isnull(df.end_date), 0)
                  .otherwise(F.when((df.end_date != df.next_start_date), 1).otherwise(0)))

# add column to classify if the product has been disabled at least once or not
df3 = df.groupBy('product_id').agg(F.sum("diff").alias("disable"))
df = df.join(df3, ["product_id"])

# get requested start date for those products have not been disabled
df1 = df.filter(df.disable == 0).groupBy("product_id").agg(F.min("start_date").alias("first_start_date"))

# get requested date for those products have been disabled once, 
# which is the first next start date at the most recent disable date 
df2 = df.filter(df.diff == 1).groupBy("product_id").agg(F.max("next_start_date").alias("first_start_date"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the below solution should solve for what you are looking to do in a more efficient way. Your current method involves a lot of "shuffle" operations (group by, sorting, joining). The below should help reduce the number of shuffle operation in your Spark job.

1. get leading start date
2. get disabled records
3. add column indicating whether product ever disabled (max of is disabled)
4. capture replacement dataset
5. get max replacement date
6. create indicator for current lifecycle records
7. filter data for current lifecycle records.

---

```
# csv input
df = spark.read.csv('productlist.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
# get ordered and unordered windows
wo = Window.partitionBy("product_id").orderBy("start_date")
wu = Window.partitionBy("product_id")
df1 = df.withColumn("lead_start_date", F.lead(col("start_date"), 1).over(wo))\
        .withColumn("is_disabled", F.when((col("end_date").isNotNull()) &
                                          ((col("end_date") != col("lead_start_date")) | (col("lead_start_date").isNull())), 1).otherwise(0))\
        .withColumn("has_been_disabled", F.max(col("is_disabled")).over(wu))\
        .withColumn("replacement_date", F.when((col("end_date").isNotNull()) &
                                          (col("end_date") == col("lead_start_date")) & (col("lead_start_date").isNotNull()), col("start_date")).otherwise(lit(None)))\
        .withColumn("max_replacement_date", F.max(col("replacement_date")).over(wu))\
        .withColumn("is_current_lifecycle_record", F.when(((col("replacement_date") == col("max_replacement_date")) & col("replacement_date").isNotNull()) |
                                                            ((col("has_been_disabled") == 0) & (col("max_replacement_date").isNull())), 1).otherwise(0)) # never disabled / replaced
# filter for current lifecycle record and select target columns
df_final = df1.filter(col("is_current_lifecycle_record") == 1).select(["product_id", "start_date"])
```